# 既存のXcodeプロジェクトでUnityを動かしたい。

Tags: xcode, unity3d, game-development

現在、iOSでネイティブアプリを開発しているのですが、
このプロジェクトでUnity5を動かしたく調べていたのですが、
よくわかりません。

簡単に言えば、ネイティブアプリとUnity5を切り替えたいのです。
以下のようなサイトの方法があるのはわかりましたが、
Unity4でされているようです。
http://sassembla.github.io/Public/2012:12:04%201-29-54/2012:12:04%201-29-54.html

既存のプロジェクトにUnity5を追加したい場合、どういった方法があるのでしょうか？
お詳しい方、どうぞご教授下さい。よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

基本的に、Unity は iOSネイティブアプリ内に組み込むことを想定していません。
上記のサイトではそれを無理やり動かすために改造をしてると思ってください。

なので、Unity5で同じことをしようとした場合、上記サイトと同じようなことをする必要があります。それには Unity5 や iOS/Xcode の知識が必要になりますが、逆にその知識があれば、上記サイトを参考にして Unity5 に対応することができるはずです。

解決策ではなく申し訳ないですが、「そもそも対応してない」と諦めることをお勧めします。